# How to save assets images in phones gallery? Using gallery_saver plugin

Tags: flutter

Hey I am using https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver plugin and I have assets images in my app using I am trying to save in phones gallery. I am doing something like this but failed. Anyone pls help me

```
  void _saveNetworkImage() async {

    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    String tempPath = tempDir.path;

    String path = tempPath + '/' + widget.imagePath;  // widget.imgPath = "assets/images/my image.jpg";

    print('ddd' + path);

    GallerySaver.saveImage(path).then((bool success) {
      setState(() {
        print('Image is saved');
      });
    });
  }
}
```

I am calling ablove function as :

```
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: _saveNetworkImage,
        icon: Icon(Icons.save),
        label: Text('Gallery'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white54,
        foregroundColor: Colors.black,
      )
```

Here my function is running but giving error

```
D/ViewRootImpl@cbdf65[MainActivity]( 3518): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/flutter ( 3518): path/data/user/0/com.thesachin.template/cache
I/flutter ( 3518): ddd/data/user/0/com.thesachin.template/cache/assets/images/aaj nhi kal karenge.jpg
E/AndroidRuntime( 3518): FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
E/AndroidRuntime( 3518): Process: com.thesachin.template, PID: 3518
E/AndroidRuntime( 3518): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.thesachin.template/cache/assets/images/aaj nhi kal karenge.jpg (No such file or directory)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3518):    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3518):    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:231)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3518):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:165)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3518):    at carnegietechnologies.gallery_saver.FileUtils.getBytesFromFile(FileUtils.kt:216)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3518):    at carnegietechnologies.gallery_saver.FileUtils.insertImage(FileUtils.kt:47)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3518):    at carnegietechnologies.gallery_saver.GallerySaver$saveMediaFile$1$success$1.invokeSuspend(GallerySaver.kt:69)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3518):    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3518):    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:238)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3518):    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3518):    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3518):    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:742)
D/ViewRootImpl@cbdf65[MainActivity]( 3518): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
D/InputMethodManager( 3518): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@460d1a9[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager( 3518): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
I/Process ( 3518): Sending signal. PID: 3518 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it with https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery_saver. Here is my working code:

```
 void _saveNetworkImage() async {

    final bytes = await rootBundle.load(widget.imagePath); // imagePath like "assets/images/my_image.jpg"

    Uint8List clockBytes = bytes.buffer.asUint8List();

    final result = ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(clockBytes);
    print(result);

  }
}
```